# Can ssh and scp to ec2 linux instance but cannot scp from linux instance to local machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, command-line, scp

I'm having a very strange issue.  When I try to SSH into my linux instance using the following line, it works.

```
ssh -i "F:\Work\Thomas Final Site\Bhasha.pem" ec2-user@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

But when I try to scp from the linux instance to my home machine running Windows 7 using the following line, I get the following error.

```
scp -i "F:\Work\Thomas Final Site\Bhasha.pem" -r ec2-user@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:~/smart-two-site "F:\Work\smart-two"

Could not create directory '/home/User/.ssh'.
The authenticity of host 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx (xx.xxx.xxx.xxx)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/home/User/.ssh/known_hosts).
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I can't understand why using the same public key I would be able to ssh into the instance, but not scp from it.  I can also scp from my local machine to the linux instance, but when I try to scp from my linux instance to my local machine from my local machine it crashes.

Any ideas as to what and why this is happening?

Comment: Are u using Cygwin by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Filezilla in sftp protocol it should work. add ppk file to settings under sftp.

Answer (score 1):

General suggestion. The way you are running `scp` for coying files between Linux and windows box will never work. SCP will presume that the file-system on either side of the connection is Linux/unix based.

Instead, when you need to copy files between Linux and windows hosts, use some software like [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/), [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) OR [BitWise](http://www.bitvise.com/ssh-client-download) ( and tons of others).

All these software have their own way of utilizing the `.pem` file which you would need to use for transferring file. Please read their respective manual.